# Calculate Sub Table Django

Tags: django, orm

I'm new on Django, I try to calculate sub table of related table.
I have two models Transaction and Detail. here is my models:

```py
    class Transaction(models.Model):
        id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
        code = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Detail(models.Model):
        id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
        transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, related_name='details', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        qty = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=False, blank=False)
        price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=False, blank=False)
```

I want to get sum of calculation (Detail.qty * Detail.price) on a single query like this:

```py
datas = Transaction.objects.all().annotate(sum=sum(qty*price))
```

How to do that on Django ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a combination usage of `F` and `Sum` in Django.

The `detail__` allows you to access foreign key `Detail`

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

datas = Transaction.objects.annotate(sum=Sum(F('detail__qty')* F('detail__price')))
```

Comment: What is F mean?

Comment: Represents the value of the field. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions

Comment: Ouh thank you, I guessed it's for a float value.

Comment: It's been solved now. Thank you for the answer.